# Plesk PHP move_uploaded_file() Live not working

Tags: php, file-upload, plesk

Im developing a website where users can upload there photo's. Locally my file upload works fine. No errors and the image uploading works fine.

However when I copy all my files to the Plesk server. I got the following error

```
File is an image - image/png.Not uploaded because of error #0
```

As you can see my image is approved by my code. My first thought was that my path was wrong. I tried

```
echo __FILE__ . "<br>";
echo dirname(__FILE__) . "<br>";
echo __DIR__ . "<br>";
```

All these paths don't work. I tried including `./` before the path. That didn't work.

my php code

```
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            // echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
            $img = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $query = "INSERT INTO portfolios(id, user_id, txt, img) VALUES(NULL,'$user_id','$txt','$img')";
            if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                exit;
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($con);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Not uploaded because of error #" . $_FILES["image"]["error"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
    }
```

I haven't used Plesk before. I though that there was something wrong with my file permissions. But then I should receive a error on file permission.

Comment: give 777 permission of folder and try again

Comment: You mean with chmod? How should I do that on ¨Plesk? Should I give permission to the upload folder or the upload file?

Comment: try this chmod($path, 0777)

Comment: So I should connect through the cli with ssh and then cd to the upload directory and execute the chmod command?